# Error while creating project on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails hence when i am trying to create new project by following command:
rails new abc
I am getting following error

rails aborted!
Psych::BadAlias: Unknown alias: default
/home/iftikhar/Desktop/abc/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>' /home/iftikhar/Desktop/abc/bin/spring:15:in` require'
/home/iftikhar/Desktop/abc/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>' ./bin/rails:3:in` load'
./bin/rails:3:in `'
Tasks: TOP => app:template
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: What version of Ruby (`ruby -v`) and Rails (`rails -v`) do you use?

Comment: ruby 3.1.0 rails 6.0.4.4

Comment: You should edit the question properly! If it's code, for example, you can select once you have pasted it, and press 'ctrl+k'.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html) Rails 6.0 is not compatible with Ruby 3.1. This makes sense because Ruby 3.1 was released just a couple of days ago but Rails 6.0.4.4 was released more than a year ago and was the last release of Rails 6.0 since then. Furthermore, it is worth noting that [Rails 6.0 is not actively maintained](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html) anymore.

I suggest using the latest Ruby on Rails (7.0.1) version when you want to start a new project. Or if you really need to work with Rails 6.0 (what I would not recommend) then you will need to downgrade Ruby to 2.7.5

Comment: Thanks alot, by upgrading to rails latest version my problem has been solved for now

Answer (score 0):

Within `config/database.yml` rename `default:` to `x-default:`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71944400/2675670